# Excel barcode description lookup

Tags: excel, vba, stock, inventory

I'm relatively new to coding and I am not having any luck so far. I am looking for a simple solution to my stock inventory problem using excel. I want to scan an item barcode and I'd like for it to automatically pull the product description from one of the upc database websites. I have seen answers that states VBA but the codes I have inputted so far are full of errors from line 1 and do not seem to work. I only need it as a simple way to check our stock levels and provide information on the title of the prodcts we stock. We have over a thousand pieces and would be tedious to do it manually.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did it fail?

Comment: why not download the data (barcode & product info) into a table on a separate sheet the use index() and match() as suggested

Comment: So I have watched a youtube video where I defined columns according to this

'Barcode' 'Product Description''Quantity'

I have then followed instructions from a youtube video which queried a search box (in this example, post codes) and generated the results into separate fields of state, address and so.

I want to follow the same model but I seem to be generating errors even on the first line. This is the video. Please bear with me as I'm an absolute beginner but willing to learn.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sZRcaaAVbg

Comment: If you have code, post the code.  If it has errors, describe the errors.  It's unlikely anyone if going to watch the video and then try to guess what the real problem is.